# How to transcribe data from bigquery to bigquery with dataflowsdk?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

When constructing a pipeline, where the source is a BigQueryIO.Read, you get a set of TableRow objects out to work with.

I essentially want to make some minor changes to those TableRow objects and then use BigQueryIO.Write to output the objects to a new table.

However, I've run into a problem where the TableRow does not actually match the original table structure, ie. it has keys with "_" in them instead of ".", and also is completely flat. (and therefore doesn't match the original schema).

Is there a step I'm missing that will make the TableRow behave correctly?
This seems like a fairly simple workflow, so I was a bit surprised when I hit this hiccup.

Goal:
`BigQueryIO.Read -> TableRow -> BigQueryIO.Write`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid the flattening of the `TableRow` by specifying [`.withoutResultFlattening()`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/io/BigQueryIO.java#L481)

As an aside and a bit of context, the flattening and the choice of underscore as a separator are both done by BigQuery and governed by the query options.

Comment: cool, I'll take a look and see what the behaviour is like. :)